# Laravel Migration - Says unknown database, but it is created

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

when I use `php artisan migrate`, i get the error `SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'databaseName'`.

But the database DOES exists! I even tried going back into terminal, logged into mysql and created the database again, and it said that database already exists!

Why is this giving me this error?

Comment: Recheck your credentials? also try changing it to all lower case?

Comment: Done that, and it is lower case ...

Comment: Also check if you are connecting to the right server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app/config/database.php` file change the default value from `databaseName` to a real database name that you are trying to use in your application, something like this (for `mysql` driver):

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'your database name', //<-- put the database name
    'username'  => 'your user name',
    'password'  => 'your password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Comment: This file is already setup correctly. I still get that error though.

Comment: What is the name of your database ?

Comment: Make sure you are working on the correct project and correct file.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. When I run: php artisan migrate.
In my case I use Vagrant with scotch box.

To solve this, enter:

1. vagrant ssh
2. cd /var/www/yourproject
3. php artisan migrate

And all work well.

Comment: I came across this SO question with the exact same process except I was doing `php artisan migrate:fresh` but both with the `:fresh` and without it, I'm receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One thing could be your casing. If you read the docs on [case sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) it says:

> the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means
>   database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS
>   X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that
>   is not case sensitive.

Then go and check your application database setting found @ `app/config/database.php`.

Something that looks like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'read' => array(
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ),
    'write' => array(
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'databaseName',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

And double check everything.

Also try using snake_case rather than camelCase for you database name.

Comment: I deleted the database (I had created it using sequel pro), and recreated it with mysql command. It is still saying no database found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had MySQL installed on this port: 3308, and in Laravel env file there was 3306.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to create the database that matches the `charset` and `collation`.

*database.php*

```
'mysql' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  ...
],
```

If you are using TablePlus, you can simply do that when you create a new DB

[image]