# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database - Database created, not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this in my .env file

```
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_KEY=m6twKy7Lr6KKFvVa7QgXUe78xfn08MLn

    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_DATABASE=laravel1
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=somepass

    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

And this is in my database.php

```
   'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

The database is created and I can see it in phpMyAdmin in browser.

[image]

But when I write `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel1'

I have seen the answers on 
[Laravel Migration - Says unknown database, but it is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750995/laravel-migration-says-unknown-database-but-it-is-created) , but that didn't helped me.

Comment: check permissions for MySQL user `SHOW GRANTS 'root'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try specifying the MySQL port that you are using. Might work out. I had a similar issue like this. Be sure to give the appropriate port where MySQL is installed in ur system(default is 3306).

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Comment: you are right i have to set port no along with hostname

Comment: I faced this, and the reason was that MySQL was using port 3307 instead of 3306 due to which this problem occurred.